# how to check ducplicates in python array and delete both the values

Tags: python

I have array with duplicate values and i want to iterate the array and delete all the duplicates .
ex: a=[1,2,3,4,4,3,5] and i want result=[1,2,5] which should delete all the duplicates values.

Answer (score 1):

Use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 5]
result = [k for k, v in Counter(a).items() if v == 1]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 5]
unique = [x for x in a if a.count(x) <= 1]
print(unique)
```

Ouput

```
[1, 2, 5]
```